# Avoid filesort in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, posts and posts_relationship.

```
posts:id, title, text, lang, timestamp

posts_relationship: id, post_id, subcategory_id
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT  posts.title,
        posts.timestamp
  FROM  posts_relationship
   INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = posts_relationship.post_id
  WHERE posts.lang = 'it' AND
        posts.timestamp <= NOW() AND 
        posts_relationship.subcategory_id = 21
  ORDER BY posts.timestamp DESC
```

I have added indexes on `posts.lang`, `posts.timestamp`, `posts_relationships.post_id`, and `posts_relationship.subcategory_id`.

But with explain I have always Temporary or Filesort.

How can I have only "Using where"?

Comment: one on `posts.id` will help. Depending on the size mysql may choose not to use an index for the smaller result sets

Comment: Replace your `<=NOW()` with static date (derived from application, as sample) and create index by `(timestamp, lang)` on table `posts`. Note, that MySQL will never be able to use more than one index, thus, index by `(timestamp, lang)` will fit `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause, but index by `subcategory_id` won't be used. So it's not 100% guarantee that you'll avoid filesort. Also filesort may mean that actually it's sort in _memory_ (which is much faster)

Comment: The file sort is for the `order by`, not the `where`.

Comment: If the query is only:
SELECT posts.title, posts.timestamp
FROM posts_taxonomy
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = posts_taxonomy.post_id
WHERE posts_taxonomy.subcategory_id = 21
ORDER BY posts.timestamp DESC

I have always Filesort... The indexes are posts.id, posts.timestamp, posts_relationship.subcategory_id

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what this line is doing:

```
    posts.timestamp <= NOW() AND
```

How do you get a timestamp that is in the future?

Without this line, then the query would look like:

```
SELECT  p.title, p.timestamp
FROM  posts_relationship pr INNER JOIN
      posts p
      ON p.id = pr.post_id
WHERE p.lang = 'it' AND
      pr.subcategory_id = 21
ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC;
```

With this query, an index on `posts(lang, timestamp, id)` might prevent the filesort.  The following version of the query would probably ensure this even more:

```
SELECT p.title, p.timestamp
FROM  posts p
WHERE p.lang = 'it' AND
      exists (select 1
              from posts_relationship pr
              where p.id = pr.post_id and pr.subcategory_id = 21
             )
ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC;
```

I don't think this query will use a file sort with the following two indexes:

```
posts(lang, id, timestamp)
posts_relationship(post_id, subcategory_id)
```

(By the way, You can keep the condition on timestamp, I just don't understand why it is necessary.)

Comment: I try to use your first Query but Filesort is always present. The timestamp in future is for hide the future posts when I want to publish a post at a specific time.

Comment: @virtusroma . . . does the last query eliminate the file sort without the additional condition on `timestamp`?

Comment: The second query product an infinite "Sending data"... I have 100.000 posts :)

Comment: @virtusroma . . . Did you create the indexes specified in the answer?

Comment: yes I have created posts(lang, timestamp, id) and posts_relationship (post_id, subcategory_id)

Comment: @virtusroma . . . Try an index on `posts(lang, id, timestamp)`.  What can I say?  Indexes are tricky.  But for ordering, `timestamp` needs to be at the end.